# I can't use more than one color in the same material in C4D

Tags: cinema4d

I am new to the 3d world and Cinema 4d software.

When I try to use gradient color and apply the material to a sphere, for example, it just uses the first color in the gradient and ignores any other colors. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moved from C4D a while back but It could be something to do with UV projection being set to a surface that isn't there.  Another reason for this could be flipped normals (in this case you would have to flip them back.  Have a look in the UV settings and change the projection type.  I'm not sure this is a lighting issue, you could always add a light to the scene but I'm under the impression there is ambient lighting by default.... Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is correct.  If you change the black end of the gradient to another color, you'll see it's not the lights.

Answer (score 0):

Cinema4D is not one of the 3d animation packages I know how to use, however it looks like you don't have any lighting in the scene.  Without lighting, there is nothing to illuminate your geometry and it will still show up as black unless your particular software has a default ambient light (some do, some do not).  I'd try adding some lighting to the scene and see if that makes it work.

My guess is that it isn't showing up on the material editor as it probably isn't doing texture mapping in that editor.  I doubt the sphere you see in the editor is actually your geometry.  Most 3d software just displays the material information on a sphere to let you see the behavior of the material and texture mapping doesn't make a ton of sense there since texture mapping will depend greatly on position of the texture on the actual geometry.